# Will apple reject app if there is trial version?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, ios-appstore, app-store-connect

Our team is working on an app where user will download and install app. He will initially have 5 days of trial period during which all of the features will be unlocked. After 5 days, some of the features will be locked and user will have to make in-app purchase (non-consumable, one time only) to unlock those features. After reading the [App Store Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/app-store/review/guidelines/#beta-testing), they state :

> Demos, betas, and trial versions of your app don’t belong on the App Store – use TestFlight instead.

My question is:

1. Is it possible that our app will get rejected?
2. Did you face any similar issue. Could you please give example.
3. What is the alternate?

Comment: Yes. Most likely.

Comment: There is an app called Acorn 5 which is a trial version of a photo editor'

Answer (score 1):

If you come out with “this is a trial” you will likely be rejected. If your app is “we do this and this” and if you want extra Y - try that, too and then decide to pay or go back to just “this and this”

If the app does something significant like Microsoft Word or Omni Graffle and then allows you to buy up to subscribe monthly / indefinitely or one time purchase an unlock to added functionality like editing a document, you should be totally in the clear - especially with one time / non consumable IAP entitlements.

Basically, the app can’t be trial after the 5 days or whatever. The key for your design is that the reviewer can clearly see some functionality that will always work for free. If your app has no long term utility past the trial, you will need an alternate model or design in all likelihood.

Answer (score 1):

Don't Mention your app name and description as Trial, Demo, Test, etc., these kind of named apps will be rejected as per the apple rules.